# How to assign values to Schema.sobjectField[]?

Tags: apex, trigger, update, after-trigger

I am working on after update trigger and I want to know what fields were updated.
I got a code on StackExchange which would serve my purpose :
But can anyone please help me on how to assign values (The fields that I want to pass to getChangedFields function) to Schema.ObjectField[] fieldList in the calling function ?

```
public Schema.sObjectField[] getChangedFields(ID recordId, Schema.sObjectField[] fieldList) {
    Schema.sObjectField[] changedFields = new list<Schema.sObjectField> ();
    SObject o1 = Trigger.oldMap.get(recordId);
    SObject o2 = Trigger.newMap.get(recordId);

    for (Schema.sObjectField field : fieldList) {
        Object v1 = o1.get(field);
        Object v2 = o2.get(field);
        if (didFieldChange(v1, v2)) {
            changedFields.add(field);
        }
    }
    return changedFields;
```

}

```
private static Boolean didFieldChange(Object v1, Object v2) {
    if (v1 == null && v2 == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (v1 != v2) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: If you're only interested in the fields that have changed, you should consider using Change Data Capture instead.

Comment: Hi , I am not using Change data capture because of the additional cost to use the pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's several ways you can do this. If you just want a hard-coded list:

```
sObjectField[] fieldList = new sObjectField[] {
  Account.Name, Account.Industry, Account.CustomField__c
};
```

Or you can get fancy with a [CMDT](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.custommetadatatypes_about.htm&type=5):

```
sObjectField[] fieldList = new sObjectField[0];
for(FieldMap__mdt value: FieldMap__mdt.getAll().values()) {
  fieldList.add(value.Field__c);
}
```

Or you could use strings:

```
Map<String, sObjectField> fieldsForObject = sObjectType.Account.fields.getMap().clone();
Set<String> fields = new Set<String> { 'name','industry','field__c' };
fieldsForObject.keySet().retainAll(fields);
sObjectField[] fieldList = fieldsForObject.values();
```

Or you can use a [field set](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.fields_about_field_sets.htm&type=5):

```
sObjectField[] fieldList = new sObjectField[0];
for(FieldSetMember member: sObjectType.Account.fieldsets.someFieldSet.getFields()) {
  fieldList.add(member.getSObjectField());
}
```

Or any combination of the above, and other ways aside from this are also possible. It's really a matter of preference.

Comment: Thank you so much !